# Using cookies to check if logged in

Tags: php, html, session, cookies

Hi I'm trying to fetch the cookie I successfully created, and compare it to a string.

The problem is that, if the user access the page directly, all the content is shown, and I don't want that to happen, I want to redirect the user to the login page.

Basically if it says yes, it will simply show me the page, and if either there is no cookie or is set to no, it will redirect me to the login.

I'm trying to use PHP. This is what I tried.

```
<?php
        $value = "Yes";
        if(isset($_COOKIE['user']) && $_COOKIE['user'] == $value)
        {
?>

<!------- HTML code goes here ------->

<?php

        }
        else{
            $cookie_name = "user";
            $cookie_value = "No";
            setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); 
            header("Location: index1.html");
        }

?>
```

This is the php I'm calling to basically check the details inputted with an SQL database.

```
<?php
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "accounts");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Error: Could not connect to database. Please try again later";
        exit;
    }

    $query="SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)
    or die("Error in query: ". mysqli_error($conn));

    $number_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($number_of_rows == 1 ){
        $cookie_name = "user";
        $cookie_value = "Yes";
        setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day

        header("Location: main.html");
        exit;
    }
    else{
        $cookie_name = "user";
        $cookie_value = "No";
        setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
        header("Location: index2.html");
    }
?>
```

Can someone help me figure out how to do this? I tried different code, and also tried sessions instead but with no luck. I have successfully stored the cookie, but can't seem to solve this part.

Thanks

Comment: can you do a session instead of cookie?

Comment: This is a very bad idea, anybody can set that cookie manually and pretend to be logged-in at your site. You should use a session for this.

Comment: You have set cookie value to 'No' but you are trying to check with 'Yes'? May I know why?

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim, in login page I assume he set the value to yes

Comment: @manix you sure you have set the value to 'Yes' in login page? Can you first check that?

Comment: hey guys, thanks for the response. I tried sessions. To tell you the truth i used cookies since i had another personal project and go it working, so its kind of new to me SESSION, but im pretty sure its not that hard.

Comment: and yes it is not a problem, if we fix this problem by using sessions instead. :)

Comment: i have also added the php, which is checking the input from the user.

Answer (score 1):

Using 'server sided session,' as @maria states, will use a lot of memory from your server recourses. Avoid using $_SESSION on web pages whenever you can.

Use this, and read the cookie values on page load to have your website quick & dry:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['user']) {
    // Save the session_id in the cookie to do your stuff in cookie data. Use explode for multiple values in the cookie.
    // check the session_id in the cookie on every page load
    // when not available, recheck, and reset the cookie
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Session is the best option for this, but if you want to use cookie then try this

```
<?php

    }
    else{
    $cookie_name = "user";
        $cookie_value = "No";
        setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); 
        ?>
        <a href="index1.html">Reload the page</a>
        <?php
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Cookie, use server sided session for this :)

```
<?php
    $value = "Yes";
    if(isset($_COOKIE['user']) && $_COOKIE['user'] == $value)
    {
?>
```

would be something like:

```
    <?php
$value = 'yes';

if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
     if ($_SESSION['user'] == $value) {
        do something..
    }
}
```

and

```
<?php

    }
    else{
    $cookie_name = "user";
        $cookie_value = "No";
        setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); 
        header("Location: index1.html");
    }

?>
```

would be:

```
<?php

    }
    else{
    $cookie_name = "user";
        $cookie_value = "No";
        $_SESSION[$cookie_name] = $cookie_value;
        header("Location: index1.html");
    }

?>
```

Total code:

```
     <?php
$value = 'yes';

if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
     if ($_SESSION['user'] == $value) {
        do something..
    }
}  else{
        $cookie_name = "user";
            $cookie_value = "No";
            $_SESSION[$cookie_name] = $cookie_value;
            header("Location: index1.html");
        }

?>
```

Comment: hey i tried applying this code, but as soon as i delete the session from the debug console, it still remains in the page.

Comment: @LukeCassar you need to use `session_start()` at the top of the PHP page, which the answer doesn't mention. Maria should add this to their answer as a prority as without it the sessions will never exist.

Comment: yes with your code, i added the session in the php code i just added, is that correct?